# Index of string containing a part of string (one word)

Tags: list, indexof

im trying to read a large file, so i thought that instead of looping with an array i decided to use a list, but I'm having some difficulties with searching a line which contains a word that needs to be searched for. Here is my code

```
    public List<string> AWfile = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\DataFolder\file.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\DataFolder\file.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    AWfile.Add(line); label1.Text = "ListWritten!"; label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int linen = AWfile.IndexOf("A102");
        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(linen);
    }
```

So my question is if there is any way to search just for a part of a word in a list instead of the whole string, because that's the only way the .IndexOf returns me anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
var result = list.Select(x => x.Contains("hello")).ToList()
```

This will result in a list with all the elements in the list which contains "hello".

And if you want to do something only with this elements:

```
list.Select(x => x.Contains("hello")).ToList().ForEach(x => DoSomething(x));
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly... you are reading in a file and adding each line to a list. Then you want to check if any of those lines contain *part* of a word.

One way of doing this would be to do a foreach loop over each of the lines in your list and checking if the line contains the partial word.

Something like:

```
foreach(var line in AWFile)
{
    if(line.Contains("PartialWordWeWant"))
    {
        // Do something with the line that contains the word we are looking for
    }
}
```